# Cocoa touch - UIView in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've created a UIView (of type ColumnView) in Interface Builder.
Is it possible to add that UIView multiple times to my window?

I'm trying to create a UIView template that I can add to my window in a couple of places but can't figure out how to do that.

I tried referencing the outlet of that UIView to 2 different IBOutlets but when I add the 2 outlets to my window, it's just treated as a single UIView.
Need the UIView to be duplicated.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Have you found an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to duplicate the view in the Inteface Builder so there are two instances. Wire  them to the outlets and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Laurent, but duplicating the view instances in Interface Builder is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to be able to change 1 view and change all views (i.e a universal view asset if you will). Thanks, Tee

Comment: Then there are two options left:
- Isolate your view into a NIB and bind it to a ViewController. This way, you will keep the ability to design it with IB. This add a controller overhead.
- Subclass UIView and do the view layout programmatically. The view is usable directly, but it is hard to design complex layout.